# How to make a func. in Ocaml, that accepts two boolean values and a char (operation) and then returns a corresponding logical value

Tags: ocaml

How can I write a function in Ocaml, that would accept two boolean values (for instance a and b, that would represent logical values 0 and 1) and a character, that would determine the operation between these two logical values? The function would then return true or false, depending on the corresponding logical value input.

There is both a semantic, as well as a syntax error in this code; well, maybe there are more, but the compiler only made a complaint about this one so far:

line 2, characters 27-30:
Error: This expression has type char but an expression was expected of type
         bool

This is what the compiler has stated about the code and here's what I've wrote:

```
let logic (a, b) operation = match operation with
| true -> if (operation == 'A') then match (a,b) with
      | (true, true) -> true
      | _ -> false
      else if (operation == '0') then match (a,b) with
      | (false,false) -> false
      | _ -> true
      else if (operation == 'X') then match (a,b) with
      | (true,true) -> false
      | (false,false) -> false
      | _ -> true
      else if (operation == 'I') then match (a,b) with
      | (true, false) -> false
      | _ -> true
      else then match (a,b) with
      | _ -> false

| false -> end;;

logic (a,b) 'A';;

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

OK, I've made some progress,at least it compiles now. However I still get an error, when I try to call the "logic" function with this line:

```
logic (true, false) 'A';;
```

The error states this:

Error: This expression has type bool 
This is not a function; it cannot be applied.

Here's what I wrote now:

```
let logic (a, b) operation = match operation with
| 'A' -> (match (a,b) with
          | (true, true) -> true
          | _ -> false
          )
| '0' -> (match (a,b) with
          | (false,false) -> false
          | _ -> true
          )
| 'X' -> (match (a,b) with
          | (true,true) -> false
          | (false,false) -> false
          | _ -> true)
| 'I' -> (match (a,b) with
          | (true, false) -> false
          | _ -> true
          )
| _ -> (match (a,b) with
        | _ -> false
        )
```

Comment: You're trying to match your operator, a character, with boolean values. Try matching the operator directly with the letters.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the comment of @Elan-Hamburger a little bit.

You have this:

```
match operation with
| true -> ...
```

But your `operation` is a character. So this won't work. You can only match `operation` against specific characters.

It's especially strange since you later compare `operator` to various characters using `==`. But the match will do that for you.

In other words you can have something like this:

```
match operation with
| 'A' -> ...
| '0' -> ...
| 'X' -> ...
| 'I' -> ...
| _ -> ...
```

There are many other problems with your code. Here are some comments:

You have nested match statements, which requires parentheses to work out right. If you try to nest without parentheses there's no way to tell when the inner match is over and further alternatives (starting with `|`) of the outer match are given.

Nested match statements look like this:

```
match expr with
| X ab ->
    (match ab with
    | A -> 4
    | B -> 2
    )
| Y _ -> 0
```

(You can also use `begin`/`end` instead of parentheses if you prefer the way that looks.)

You're using `==` to compare values. The ordinary equality comparison operator is `=`. The special operator `==` should only be used when you have a specific reason for it.

You have code that reads like this:

```
else then match ...
```

This can't be syntactically correct. Possibly the `then` is left over from an edit.

You can simplify this expression

```
match (a, b) with
| _ -> false
```

to this simpler expression:

```
false
```

**Update**

I can't reproduce your new reported problem. In fact your new code works OK for me in two quick tests.

```
. . .
val logic : bool * bool -> char -> bool = <fun>
# logic (true, false) 'A';;
- : bool = false
# logic (true, true) 'A';;
- : bool = true
```

Possibly there was some extraneous input (or extraneous definitions) in your top-level session. I suggest just trying again with a fresh session.